# Executing a Remote Bat File from A Remote Server

Tags: powershell

Want to do something like this but only returns the string of the scriptblock and no output. How would I get this bat file to execute and produce the desired output csv file?

```
Invoke-Command -Computer server1 -ScriptBlock {"\\server2\shared\Compliance\K3\K3 Rec Tool\LimitsRecon\test.bat"}
```

Comment: [How to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
{ & "\\server2\shared\Compliance\K3\K3 Rec Tool\LimitsRecon\test.bat" }
```

Comment: Doesn't like that syntax:The term '\\server2\shared\Compliance\K3\K3 Rec Tool\LimitsRecon\test.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\server2\s...reconmizuho.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : server1

Comment: Syntax is fine, that's an error saying your batch file doesn't exist (or you don't have permission to access it).

Comment: Can you use UNC paths in a script block? I can traverse to that directory and file using windows explorer without an issue. The file does exist and the account I am using can execute the bat from cmd.exe without issue.

Comment: Ohh, maybe `{ & """\\server2\shared\Compliance\K3\K3 Rec Tool\LimitsRecon\test.bat""" }` to quote the path inside the string and deal with the spaces?